# SliverAppbar with Search and button on Scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a scrolling animation behaviour in Flutter.

On Luanch of the app we have below screen with Search bar on (Below image)

[image]

and when scroll down, seach bar should move on SliverApp bar as below screen

[image]

Please guide me how to implement this behaviour..

Your guidance would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 `SliverPersistentHeader` inside a `CustomScrollView`.

A first one containing your image and text field, a second containing your bottom items. When scrolling you'll be able to update your first header to hide the picture.

### Code Sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliverAppBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;

  const SliverAppBarPage({super.key, required this.imageUrl});

  @override
  State<SliverAppBarPage> createState() => _SliverAppBarPageState();
}

class _SliverAppBarPageState extends State<SliverAppBarPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: AppBarDelegate(imageUrl: widget.imageUrl),
            pinned: true,
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            delegate: BottomDelegate(),
            pinned: true,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text('$index'));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final String imageUrl;

  AppBarDelegate({required this.imageUrl});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final opacity = shrinkOffset / maxExtent;
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: size.width,
          height: double.maxFinite,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(imageUrl), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(opacity),
          ),
        ),
        SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                ),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: 'Search',
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 300.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 90.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class BottomDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double height;

  BottomDelegate({this.height = 50.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 4,
      child: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 4),
        itemCount: 50,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 8),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purple[800],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: Text('$index', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

[Try the live example on zapp.run](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zx1206yux130?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/sliver_appbar_page.dart)

Answer (score 0):

use nested scrollview  and set pinned true

Comment: already tried this

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.